# Why cannot I use html entities in anonymous replaced elements?

Tags: css, html-entities

Anonymous replaced elements are content used with `:before` or `:after`

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/content

Here is an example:

```
.valid:after {
  content: '&lt;';
  color: green;
}

.invalid:after {
  content: '&gt;';
  color: red;
}
```

The problem is HTML entities are not replaced by their caracters and I still see their code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS isn't HTML. Simply use

```
.valid:after {
  content: '<';
  color: green;
}
```

In case of need, you may also escape your characters using the unicode hexa.

For example for ▶ :

```
.valid:after {
  content: '\25B6';
  color: green;
}
```

But you don't need to escape `<` nor `>`, even if you embed your CSS in the `<style>` element of an HTML file.

Just in case (it might be less disturbing to your HTML editor), their codes would be `\003C` and `\003E`.

Comment: `&lt;` and `&gt;` where just examples, in fact I want a check/cross whose entities are `&#x2713;` and `&#x2717;` then it seems to work with `\2713` nor `\2717` thank you !